# Testing React components with a .jsx extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to the React framework and right now I am exploring the way to test components in React. I was following this example: `https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/test-reactjs-components-karma-webpack` for setting up a unit testing framework for React using mocha and karma.

I realized that all my components had .jsx extensions and not .js, and I dug deeper. I understood the components need to be built before they could be imported/used.

I tried using this example: `http://www.bebetterdeveloper.com/coding/getting-started-react-mocha.html`. But this does not cover karma.

How do I use karma so that the jsx files are built and then imported?

I am using gulp for building the artifacts and my NodeJS version is 5.6

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use Karma?  I can post an answer giving you my complete testing setup, but I use Mocha and Chai, and I have no need for a test-runner like Karma.

Comment: Well, no specific reason for using Karma. I was following the tutorial and apparently most examples something like karma or jasmine. So yeah. But then, a followup question would be, is it not possible using Karma, Mocha and gulp ?

Comment: It's definitely possible, I just haven't done it before, so I wouldn't be able to post an answer for you.  But if you're okay with ditching Karma or Jasmine, I can post my setup for you.

Comment: I was using karma for code coverage, but I am guessing you can do that through istanbul as well?
If you're okay posting your code snippet, I can definitely have that as a reference. Worst case, ditch karma and use mocha with chai

Comment: Yes, I use Mocha, Chai, Istanbul, and Enzyme for my React testing setup.  I can post an answer in about an hour or so.

Comment: Sure, thanks! That would be super helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example for unit testing React components using Mocha, Chai, and a jsdom helper, which is used in place of a test runner like Karma.

You will need the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^15.1.0",
  "react-dom": "^15.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
  "babel-register": "^6.9.0",
  "chai": "^3.5.0",
  "jsdom": "^9.3.0",
  "mocha": "^2.5.3"
}
```

It's also useful to have an npm script that points to mocha - `npm run test` will execute your tests:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha"
},
```

After you have your dependencies set up, you'll want a directory structure that looks like this:

```
.
├── /src
│   └── component-to-test.js
├── /test
│   ├── /unit
│   │   └── component-to-test.spec.js
│   ├── /util
│   │   └── jsdom.js
│   └── mocha.opts
├── .babelrc
└── package.json
```

We'll start off with your `.babelrc` file.  You'll need [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your JSX into JavaScript.  If you want to use ES6 syntax (highly recommended), Babel will help with that too.  I've included both of these presets in the devDependencies.

**.babelrc:**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

Next, we'll look at the [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) helper.  This is needed in order to render React components into an in-memory DOM, which is typically handled by a test runner like Karma.

**jsdom.js:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var jsdom = require('jsdom'),
        baseHTML,
        window;

    if (!global.window) {
        baseHTML = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head lang="en"><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Tests</title></head><body></body></html>';
        window = jsdom.jsdom(baseHTML).defaultView;

        global.window = window;
        global.document = window.document;
        global.navigator = window.navigator;
    }

}());
```

In order to leverage this jsdom helper for use in our mocha tests, we'll need to set up a `mocha.opts` file that specifies a few configuration options.  We'll add a compiler that will tell Babel to pre-process the tests, and we'll `require` the jsdom helper so React has a DOM to use to render components.

**mocha.opts:**

```
--compilers js:babel-register
--recursive
--reporter spec
--ui bdd
--require ./test/util/jsdom.js
```

Finally, we can start testing React components.  As an example, here is a simple component that we can test.

**test-component.js:**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="test-component">Here is a test component</div>
        );
    }
}
```

And here is a test suite that will test this component's markup.

**test-component.spec.js:**

```
import TestComponent from '../../src/test-component';
import {expect} from 'chai';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactTestUtils from '../../node_modules/react/lib/ReactTestUtils';

describe('Test Component', () => {
    let renderedNode;

    function renderComponent() {
        const componentElement = React.createElement(TestComponent),
            renderedElement = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(componentElement);

        renderedNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(renderedElement);
    }

    beforeEach(() => {
        renderComponent();
    });

    it('should exist with the correct markup', () => {
        expect(renderedNode.tagName).to.equal('DIV');
        expect(renderedNode.className).to.equal('test-component');
        expect(renderedNode.textContent).to.equal('Here is a test component');
    });
});
```

At this point, the command `npm run test` should result in a single passing test.

And that's it!  If you're looking for more advanced testing techniques, you can completely avoid the need for a jsdom helper and use shallow rendering for your tests.  I highly recommend [Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) if you want to take this approach.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: This is great. But then again, all your react component files have the extension of .js and not .jsx. Will that not affect the tests?

Comment: Nope, you can use either extension.  The only difference is that your `import` statement in the test needs to include the `.jsx` file extension.  Omitting extensions is only allowed for files ending in `.js`.

Comment: Aha okay. I'll try this out. This is great. Thank you!